# How to delete comments for java project with sed?

Tags: bash, sed, java

I have a Java project, in which I have JavaDoc comments

```
/** ... */
```

other multi-line-comments

```
/* ... */
```

line comments

```
// ...
```

and my own "explanatory comments"

```
//* ...
```

When I release my code, I would like to have all line comments removed - not the other comments though. I though I would do it with sed, but so far I have not been successful. I am trying the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -d $'\0' findfile ; do
  echo "${findfile}"
  mv "${findfile}" "${findfile}".veryold
  cat "${findfile}".veryold | sed -e 's|//[^\*"]*[^"]*||' -e 's/[ ^I]*$//' | grep -A1 . | grep -v '^--$' > "${findfile}"
  rm -f "${findfile}".veryold
done < <(find "${1}" -type f -print0)
```

What am doing wrong? Note that // in "..." should not be removed, since they might be part of an URL.

The crucial part is

```
-e 's|//[^\*"]*[^"]*||'
```

Comment: First of all, you should create a collection of testlines, which can be used, to see, if a solution works and might be further extended, if it misses important cases.

Answer (score 1):

At first, your script could be simplified to a one-liner:

```
find "$1" -type f -name '*.java' -print -exec sed -i -e '...' '{}' \;
```

Second, this is a problem which is hardly solvable using regular expressions, since their grammar does not support context-sensitivity. That means you cannot know if a `//` is inside a string literal or not.

Ignoring that fact, you might try it with:

```
s|//[^*"][^"]*$||
```

This assumes that you don't use double quotes as part of your comments.

Comment: I  don't see how your regex takes care of left over white space and two consecutive blank lines. Also it seems that your answer is very similar to my try: However you did not escape the asterik inside the first brackets - is that not necessary?

Comment: Why not 's|//[^\*"]*[^"]*$||' as I wrote? Why did you leave out the second asterisk?

Comment: Inside character classes (the brackets), you don't need to escape meta-characters. This would be illogical and even could be wrong! (remember, a character class *always* matches exactly *one* character - so `[\*]` could mean: accept one of `\ ` and `*` OR only accept `*`). Your regex is just a complicated way of the regex `//[^"]*$` since the second character class is a superset of the first and both are optional (ie. repeated zero times).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure sed can do complex matches other multiple lines.

With perl remove all comments :

```
perl -e '$_=join("",<>);s%/\*.*?\*/%%gs;s%//.*$%%gm;print' SomeFile.java
```

With perl remove all non-javadoc comments outside of pairs of "" :

```
perl -e '$_=join("",<>);s%/\*([^*].*?)?\*/%%gs;s%^([^\"\n\r]*(\"[^\"\n\r]*\"[^\"\n\r]*?)*?)//([^*\n\r].*)?$%$1%gm;print' SomeFile.java
```

Here is a more compact version with search of all *.java files and generation of .bak files :

```
 find . -name '*.java' -print0 | xargs -r -0 perl -n -p -0 -i.bak -e 's%/\*([^*].*?)?\*/%%gs;s%^([^\"\n\r]*(\"[^\"\n\r]*\"[^\"\n\r]*?)*?)//([^*\n\r].*)?$%$1%gm'
```

But this will remove // inside /** */

A more complex script would be necessary to avoid that :

You'll have to replace /** */ with __temp_comment_# (replace # with an changing number)

then replace "..." with __temp_quote_#

then remove comment

then change back __temp_quote_# and __temp_comment_# to original text

Comment: "But this will remove // inside /** */" This is okay. But how do I make sure that //*, //**, //*** etc. are not removed, while // ... without a directly following asterisk is removed?

Comment: // will be removed, but not //* : this is already included in my second expression. This is made with //([^*\n\r].*)?$ : // follow by nothing or any characters but * and carry return, then anything to the end of line.

Comment: How do I include your expression into a (long) bash command? Do I just use what cbley wrote and use your perl instead of his sed command or do I use my script above?

Comment: I edited my answer with the search of *.java files.